# Having trouble scraping multiple pages in Python in Selenium- only pulls first page, or last page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

Somewhat new to scraping, overall goal is to scrape and insert into CSV. At the moment, I'm having issues with scraping javascript on predetermined pages. The scraper as I have it will pull, but it will only pull from page 1, even when feeding it through a for loop. Have tried tons of variations but can't seem to get it to work. Any tips/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint

pages = np.arange(1, 4, 1)

date2 = []
time2 = []

for page in pages:

    page="https://web.tmxmoney.com/news.php?qm_symbol=BNS#qmpage" +str(page)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(page)
    sleep(randint(2,10))
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

for text in pages:
    date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="date"]')
    time = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="auther"]')

for item in date:
    text1 = item.text
    print(text1)

for item in time:
    text2 = item.text
    print(text2)
```

Comment: Also never use sleep with selenium use webdriver wait or implicit wait.

Comment: Look at date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="date"]') matches 171 items.  If you check their xpaths //*[@id="page1"]/div[1]/div[1] and //*[@id="page2"]/div[1]/div[1]. Try using their id when changing pages.

Comment: Wait was using wait before, tutorial I was following used sleep, but will adjust. I guess I could add a date1, date2, per page? There's about 15 items of "date" I want to pull per page. I added the ID before in front of the class in the xpath variable and it had the same problem tbh.  Apprecjate the imput. Was messing around with a tutorial structure and it hasnt worked the way I've wanted

Comment: If you look at the page you'll notice 15 tags named <div id="page1" class="pages" style="display: block;"> you can grab all of these tags without switching pages and then loop them. Then access all the dates and times.

Comment: Update: using for loops within the initial page-1, page-2 loop to look for each  listing of Date worked. Downside:TMX updated their website and uses all new tags now hahaha

Answer (score 0):

I think your for-loops are a little weird. Based on my guess as to your intentions, I adjusted your code.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint

pages = np.arange(1, 4, 1)

date2 = []
time2 = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

for page in pages:

    page="https://web.tmxmoney.com/news.php?qm_symbol=BNS#qmpage" +str(page)
    driver.get(page)
    sleep(randint(2,10))
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="date"]')
    time = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="auther"]')

    for item in date:
        text1 = item.text
        print(text1)
    
    for item in time:
        text2 = item.text
        print(text2)
```

Comment: Hi, @bad_at_math , if this is the solution to your problem, please [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or [Vote up it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) :)